# Display a menu on all pages except a specific page type

Tags: routes

In my site, I have a menu that should be displayed on all pages, except on pages of a certain type.

In "admin -> structure -> blocks" I can set the visibility parameters of this menu to "pages of a certain type", and check all page types except the one I dont want. This has 2 problems :

1) whenever I add a new page type, I need to update this menu visibility (minor problem)

2) the menu will not be visible except on pages. For example, on the contact page, there is no menu.

What should be the right way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module for better and more advanced handling of blocks.

Alternatively, you could use [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/context) to create a unique url for that content type (like mysite.com/type/content ) and set the block to show up everywhere, excluding 'type/*'. If you do this, make sure to rebuild your urls.

Answer (score 1):

If you use aliases for the content type using 'pathauto' module you can select types by their path.  Then you would set the block as follows:
Select the "configure" option for the specific block
select the pages tab 
select the radio button "All pages except those listed".

List the pages to omit similar to this:

```
contentType1/*
contenttype2/* ( one type per line)
```